# error: no suitable constructor found for JsonArrayRequest

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, api

**I'm a programming student building an Android App that uses a api json url and I'm getting a no suitable constructor found for JsonArrayRequest**

***Here is the error:***

> C:\Users\jerma\AndroidStudioProjects\VolleyParsing\app\src\main\java\com\jermainebjonesgmail\volleyparsing\MainActivity.java:37:
>   error: no suitable constructor found for
>   JsonArrayRequest(int,String,>,)
>           JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET,
>                                           ^
>       constructor JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(String,Listener,ErrorListener)
>   is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       constructor JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(int,String,JSONArray,Listener,ErrorListener)
>   is not applicable

***Here is my code:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String URL = "https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/units";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET,
            URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            VolleyLog.d("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(arrayRequest);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating JsonArrayRequest in a wrong way. see [java docs](https://afzaln.com/volley/index.html?com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.html), for constructor.

**Constructor Summary**

```
JsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
      Creates a new request.
```

JsonArrayRequest can be created as below:

```
Request request = new JsonArrayRequest(httpMethod, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            serverCallback.onAPIResponse(apiTag, response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            serverCallback.onErrorResponse(apiTag, error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
        }
    };
```

Please find sample code [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest)